# Apply border that changes color depending on the background color it's applied at

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to implement the following. A title with a vertical line which crosses over below (or above) the next container element.

I tried an approach using the `:after` pseudoselector but I can't achieve all the requirements:

1. The line's color should change (and should be customizable independently by CSS) when it's over or under the next element
2. The title with the line should be possible to be placed inside the box that leads in the next section (see prototype below)

Could you suggest some sustainable and scalable solutions? (I am thinking: svg?)

[image: border]

---

[image]

here's my non-working prototype:

```css
.title-with-stripe {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.title-with-stripe:after {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    top: 110%;
    left: 50%;
}
.box {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.box-info {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="title-with-stripe">Companies</p>
<div class="box">the line in here should change color, and ideally we can define that color
<p class="title-with-stripe">Contact info</p>
</div>
<div class="box-info">half of the line should spill in here</div>
```

Comment: What's not working with your prototype? Is it only the color?

Comment: You can use some rgba `background-color` for the following sections while adding some lower `z-index` for the `:after` pseudo element.

Comment: Should the `div` be on top of the line and the background colour of the div be an rgba? - `{background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);}`

Comment: try using blend mode in the object

Comment: Does distance between title and below block stays constant/pre-defined?

Comment: Please check the updated question. There are 2 requirements for this to work ! thanks

Comment: Why is the second title with the first `div`? Looks confusing to me. Are you in a situation where you can't touch the HTML file to modify it?

Comment: @Harry I definitely can fully change the HTML. but visually, these "titles" sometimes fall inside the blocks. (code-wise, we can put em anywhere we want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `before`, `after`, and opacity would work, although it's not the most elegant of codes.

```css
.title-with-stripe {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.title-with-stripe:before {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    top: 110%;
    left: 50%;
}
.title-with-stripe:after {
    border-left: 1px solid #BADA55;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    top: calc(110% + 50px);
    left: 50%;
}
.box {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="title-with-stripe">Companies</p>
<div class="box">the line in here should change color, and ideally we can define that color</div>
```

Comment: could be, I don't mind using both before and after although check the (2) condition of my question?

Comment: the problem with this one is that beyond using "opacity" or "rgba" you can't really have a totally different color, because the :after line is sitting on top of :before .. (try setting border-left to #fff for :after and removing the opacity)

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd condition. I thought the line had to be some sort of similar color as the background, I changed that, I updated the snippet.

Comment: To be honest, though, I would just add a class to the container, something like ".with-line" and then absolute position the line for the upper container and for the lower container, giving them each another color.

Comment: Thanks for the two alternatives :) I'll use this one for now although the second one might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the line above the rest and using mix-blend-mode:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

This will cause the line to take some considerations about the colors behind in order to determine the final colour.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but browser support is definitely problematic http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 0):

In my answer earlier I commented "I would do it in another way", here's what I meant:

```css
.title-with-stripe {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.box-info {
  background: green;
}

.stripe-bottom {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.stripe-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1px;
}

.stripe-top {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.stripe-top:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1px;
}

.type1:after, .type1:before {
  background: #CF4D2B;
}
.type2:after, .type2:before {
  background: green;
}
.type3:after, .type3:before {
  background: blue;
}
.type4:after, .type4:before {
  background: orange;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<p class="title-with-stripe stripe-bottom type1">Companies</p>
<div class="box stripe-top type2">the line in here should change color, and ideally we can define that color
<p class="title-with-stripe stripe-bottom type3">Contact info</p>
</div>
<div class="box-info stripe-top type4">half of the line should spill in here</div>
```